# Presenting An Error from App delegate -- Google Signin

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase in my app and I want to add google signin functions. According to Google, I should add the sign function to my Appdelegate. My Problem is that if I want to perform the login from the appdelegate how could I present Error to the user. I tried the following code.

```
  public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){

    if let error = error {
        print()
        let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }
    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                      accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { [weak self](user, error1) in
        if(error != nil){

            let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error1!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self?.window?.rootViewController?.present(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

And I get the following error

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f864b62bef0> on <SFSafariViewController: 0x7f864b40edb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

what should I do ?

Comment: your  `self.window?.rootViewController.view` seems not to be in your view. Post the code where you set  self.window?.rootViewController to have a look.

Comment: I have a view controller that call the sign in method. I never actually set the rootViewController.

Comment: Are you using any Navigation Controller?Also update your Q with your storyboard hierarchy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says, your `self.window?.rootViewController` is of type `SFSafariViewController` and its `.view is not in the window hierarchy` at the moment you are calling `sign()`. (If you do not set the `rootViewController` programatically, you probably set it in `Storyboard` (the ViewController with the big arrow on the left side (->))

Probably you are showing another `UIViewController` at the moment you call sign().

Two options:

1) Move the `sign()` method to the `UIViewController` who is calling it

Assuming you have a `UIViewController` named `MyLoginViewController` for login, move your `sign()` method from the `AppDelegate` to `MyLoginViewController` and replace `self?.window?.rootViewController?` with `self`:

```
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){

    if let error = error {
        print()
        let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }
    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                  accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { [weak self](user, error1) in
    if(error != nil){

        let importantAlert: UIAlertController =     UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error1!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

2) Pass ViewController as argument

If you want to keep the `sign()` method at a global place, i.e. in `AppDelegate`, add an argument to your `sign()` method to pass the calling `UIViewCOntroller`:

In AppDelegate:

```
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, presenting viewController: UIVIewController, withError error: Error!){

    if let error = error {
        print()
        let importantAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        viewController.present(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }
    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                  accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { [weak self](user, error1) in
    if(error != nil){

        let importantAlert: UIAlertController =     UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error1!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            viewController.present(importantAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

and call it like this in the currently presented `UIViewController`:

```
sign(yourGIDSignIn, didSignInFor: yourGIDGoogleUser, presenting: self, withError: yourError)
```